# To Avoid the white space before negative sign to be treated as mathord

Tags: spacing

Some time we write `a=b\qquad -c=-d`

then the negative sign was treated as minus sign, you know what happened: the space arround the sign is incorrect.

Although it can be done with `{-}c=-d` or `\mathord{-}c=-d`, I think there might be an elegant solution.

Answer (score 9):

It is not very difficult to use `{-}`. However, I seldom need to use `a=b\qquad -c=-d` in my document.

In fact, where you use `a=b\qquad -c=-d`, you may use:

```
$a=b$, $-c=-d$
```

or

```
\begin{align*}
a&=b & -c&=-d
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `\qquad` isn't taken into account for the math spacing, so it's as if you typed `a=b-c=-d`. To automatically solve this problem, you can redefine `\quad` and `\qquad` by adding a `\mathclose{}` before them and a `\mathopen{}` after. To make them still usable in text mode, you need to test math mode with `\ifmmode`, begining by the standard `\relax` in that case:

[image: effect of the new quad and qquad macros]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\quad}{\relax\ifmmode\mathclose{}\fi
                     \hskip 1em\relax
                     \ifmmode\mathopen{}\fi}
\renewcommand{\qquad}{\relax\ifmmode\mathclose{}\fi
                      \hskip 2em\relax
                      \ifmmode\mathopen{}\fi}
\begin{document}
\[a=b{,}\qquad -c=-d.\]
or
\[a=b \quad \text{and} \quad -c=-d.\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are there too many `\relax`'s? I can't see any advantage to using `\relax`.

Comment: @Leo Liu: The `\relax` before `\ifmmode` is to ward against the side effect mentioned in the *TeXbook*, page 240 (relative to when TeX is looking for an `\omit` in an `\halign`); it is nearly systematically used in the LaTeX kernel. The `\relax` after `\hskip` is to avoid `\quad plus` (in text mode) to think the `plus` is the sequel of `1em` as in `\hskip 1em plus 3pt`.