# Redefine vertical bar <|>: How to typeset negative sign correctly?

Tags: spacing, typography

In my document I have to typeset several points with coordinates.

**Example**

```
\(P(-3|-2)\)
```

**Output**

[image]

As you can see LaTeX handles the second sign as an *minus sign* (binary operator) whereas it's an *negative sign* (unary operator). I know that a solution would be to enclose the second sign in curly braces like `\(P(-3|{-}2)\)` ([Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9833/to-avoid-the-white-space-before-negative-sign-to-be-treated-as-mathord)).

> How can I redefine the vertical bar so that LaTeX sets the spaces
>   correctly?

I don't want to change it manually by adding curly braces because I have hundreds of coordinates to change (collection of exercises). As far as I know I have to add `\mathclose{}` and `\mathopen{}` to the vertical bar ([Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9849/101831)).

Comment: you can just use `\lvert`

Comment: I don't want to change it manually. I am looking for a redefine-command or a macro.

Comment: It may break other things, but \catcode`|=\active \def|{\mathopen\vert\mathclose}

Comment: Take it as a lesson that is it never a good idea to use `|` as a syntax. In most manuscripts I edit, one of my goals are: no `|` when I'm done. `|` is used for for many things that, as Steven mentions, of you need to change something for a single use, then thee will be collateral damage.

Comment: So `\(P(-3\lvert-2)\)` would be the official syntax? I am asking because there are several [ways to typeset a vertical bar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506/101831) in LaTeX.

Comment: What is the expression supposed to mean, mathematically?

Comment: It's a point called P with -3 as x-coordinate and -2 as y-coordinate. In Germany we use to write it like this (I think).

Comment: Consider making the `|` into a proper binary operator using `mathbin`: `\(P(-3\mathbin{|}-2)\)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do `\(P(-3|{-2})\)`, but it would be error prone.

You're better to define a macro for your coordinates, so you are not tied to a particular notation. Suppose somebody turns up ordering you to use a semicolon for separating coordinates: would you like to go through your long document and changing all bars appearing in that context to semicolons? I wouldn't. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\coord}[3]{%
  #1% the point's name
  (#2\mathclose{}\,\vert\,\mathopen{}#3)%
}

\begin{document}

A point \( \coord{P}{-3}{-2} \) (good)

A point \( P(-3|{-2}) \) (bad)

\end{document}
```

The empty `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` atoms match the parentheses and help into keeping things properly segregated.

You're not compelled to use `\,` on either side of `\vert`, but I believe it's better. In any case, just changing the definition of `\coord` would solve the tough situation described above.

[image]

You can still use an input style resembling the output, with the help of `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coord}{ u( u| u) }{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{#1}% the point's name (optional)
  (#2\mathclose{}\,\vert\,\mathopen{}#3)%
}

\begin{document}

A point \( \coord P(-3|-2) \)

A point \( \coord(-3|-2) \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is a test case where the `\mathclose{}` becomes relevant?

Comment: @daleif I like symmetry. `;-)`

Comment: The problem with a missing `\mathopen` comes up far more often than a missing `\mathclose`, so I just wanted an example of the later for my mental archive.

Comment: @daleif I can't think to any real world case, since the first coordinate will always end with an ordinary atom. So `\mathclose{}` is not really necessary, I agree.

Comment: it was also a more general question

Comment: @daleif Then I can think to some postfix sign: somebody uses `0-` to denote a negative number close to zero.